# While scanf!=EOF or scanf==1?

Tags: c, scanf

*Ceteris paribus* (well formed data, good buffering practices and what not), is there a reason why I prefer to loop while the return of `scanf` is 1, rather than `!EOF`? I may have read this somewhere, or whatever, but I may have it wrong as well. What do other people think?

Comment: Somewhat related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970880/using-scanf-in-a-while-loop

Comment: @Steve: heh. Academia does that to you... never noticed, and nice touch italicizing it... you obviously come from academia as well. :)

Comment: I'm afraid not - just a solidly traditional English school education in the 70s.

Comment: If that was the infamous "grammar schools", you win. English schools trump anything in the English-language educational system. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`scanf` returns the number of items succesfully converted ... or EOF on error. So code the condition the way it makes sense.

```
scanfresult = scanf(...);
while (scanfresult != EOF) /* while scanf didn't error */
while (scanfresult == 1) /* while scanf performed 1 assignment */
while (scanfresult > 2) /* while scanf performed 3 or more assignments */
```

Contrived example

```
scanfresult = scanf("%d", &a);
/* type "forty two" */
if (scanfresult != EOF) /* not scanf error; runs, but `a` hasn't been assigned */;
if (scanfresult != 1) /* `a` hasn't been assigned */;
```

---

**Edit: added another more contrived example**

```
int a[5], b[5];
printf("Enter up to 5 pairs of numbers\n");
scanfresult = scanf("%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d", a+0,b+0,a+1,b+1,a+2,b+2,a+3,b+3,a+4,b+4);
switch (scanfresult) {
case EOF: assert(0 && "this didn't happen"); break;
case 1: case 3: case 5: case 7: case 9:
    printf("I said **pairs of numbers**\n");
    break;
case 0:
    printf("What am I supposed to do with no numbers?\n");
    break;
default:
    pairs = scanfresult / 2;
    dealwithpairs(a, b, pairs);
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you want to do with malformed input - if your scan pattern isn't matched, you can get `0` returned. So if you handle that case outside the loop (for example if you treat it the same as an input error), then compare with `1` (or however many items there are in your scanf call).

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/

> On success, the function returns the
>   number of items succesfully read. This
>   count can match the expected number of
>   readings or fewer, even zero, if a
>   matching failure happens. In the case
>   of an input failure before any data
>   could be successfully read, EOF is
>   returned.

The only way to be sure that you read the number of items intended is to compare the return value to that number.

Comment: The quoted text is incorrect. Items read (but not stored) using formats like `%*d` are **not counted** in the return value. www.cplusplus.com does not seem to be a good source for accurate info about the C standard library. If you'd like an online reference you can link to, POSIX is authoritative; for standard C functions with POSIX extensions, it has the extension parts marked in "CX" blocks. See http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html