# while(scanf) is infinite looping?

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, scanf, infinite

The code is supposed to accept a line of user input containing different characters and then print out one line containing only the letters. For example, Cat8h08er64832&*^ine would be Catherine. However, the code works and outputs "Catherine" however the program doesn't exit... [see picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZMWh.png) I'm not sure if the loop is just looping infinitely or...

```
int main(void){

  int i=0, j=0;
  char userString[1000];
  char alphabet[1000];

  printf("Please enter a string: ");

  while(scanf("%c", &userString[i])){
    if((userString[i]>='A' && userString[i]<='Z')||(userString[i]>='a'&&userString[i]<='z')){
        alphabet[j]=userString[i];
        printf("%c", alphabet[j]);
        j++;
     }
     i++;
   }
   printf("\n");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no exit condition for the loop. What should be the exit condition?

Comment: `scanf` returns `EOF` when it reaches the end of the input (when you type `Ctl-d`). You're not checking for that. The `%c` operator can never return 0 conversions, because any character matches it.

Comment: I thought that while(scanf("%c", &userString[i])) would loop until the end of the user input (enter key)? Does it not?

Comment: @Barmar ohh I see that makes a lot of sense.

Comment: If you want to read a single line of input, use `fgets` to read into an array. Then loop over the characters of the array.

Comment: if I loop until the enter key is pressed, the theoretically the following should work right?
while(scanf("%c", &userString[i]) != '\n')
however I encounter the same issue

Comment: Do not just post external links, or images in general. Instead paste text **in** you question.

Comment: @QuinnTai No. That will still allow the loop to continue when scanf returns EOF, since EOF (usually) == -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're checking that `scanf` is finished by checking for the return value `0`. `scanf` returns `EOF` (usually, -1) when there is no more input. So if you get some input (return 1) then no more input (return -1), your loop won't ever exit.

Change the `scanf` condition to check for `<> EOF`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2970916/3195526) also explains it quite well.

Comment: while(scanf("%c", &userString[i]) != EOF) doesn't work as well. Is this because %c accepts the enter key (\n) as a valid input, and doesn't recognize that I want it to terminate once the enter key is pressed?

Comment: Sounds likely. scanf is tricky to get working with human input. You may need to check for multiple termination values and error conditions.

Comment: I ended up using fgets and looping through there. Thanks for all your help anyways.

Comment: Good stuff. fgets protects you from some of the many pitfalls in scanf.